# Why is "Why did she washed her hairs?" incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

> "Why did she washed her hairs?"

What's wrong with this sentence?

Comment: At least, it should be **did wash...**.

Comment: After do/does/did you always have a bare infinitive, no finite form as washed.

Answer (score 5):

> Why did she washed her hairs?

The sentence is not correct grammatically for the following reasons:

"Did" is the past tense of "do".  When you use it as an auxiliary or helping verb to form a sentence in the interrogative or negative in the past, it takes the first form of a verb.

Second, hair is a  countable and uncountable noun.  When you refer to all the hairs on your head, you use "hair". The correct sentence is as follows:

> Why did she wash her hair?

Comment: Personally, I'm more comfortable with either "the plain form" or "the base form", if we want to avoid technical terms. (I think "the first form" is not wrong, but it could be ambiguous whether it's plural or singular.)